# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: reactjs, redux, typeerror

I'm trying to do a balance of incomes/expenses at my budget admin app and i keep getting this error at my balance component: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type').

I think the problem may be related with the state I bring from my reducer that comes duplicated, 2 times with an empty array [] and 2 times full. I tried a lot but couldn't fix it.. any idea what it could be??

This is my balance component code:

```
export default function Balance(){

    const operations = useSelector((state) => state.operations);

    console.log(operations);
    //Shows 4 arrays, 2 empty and 2 full

    const [total, setTotal] = React.useState([]);

    const operationsListCopy = [...operations];

    React.useEffect(() => {

        let entryArray = operationsListCopy.filter((oneOperation) => oneOperation.type == 'INCOME');
        let entryArrayTotal = entryArray?.reduce((amount, item) => item.amount + amount, 0);

        let exitArray = operationsListCopy.filter((oneOperation) => oneOperation.type == 'EXPENSE');
        let exitArrayTotal = exitArray?.reduce((amount, item) => item.amount + amount, 0);
            
        let arrayTotal = entryArrayTotal - exitArrayTotal;

        setTotal(arrayTotal);
    }, [operations]);
```

Comment: What do you see when you try to `console.log(operationsListCopy)`? What is the type of each json object in the array.

Comment: Hi, i get the same response: 2 empty arrays and 2 full. Empty arrays [], full arrays [{…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: JSON object: {id: 37, reason: 'TEST01', amount: 1000, date: '2021-10-10T03:00:00.000Z', type: 'INCOME'}

Comment: 2 empty and 2 full array log just shows that your component re-renders multiple times. The real issue is, your array elements don't have the field `type` at some point. Can you verify all your array elements have the field `type`?

Comment: Yes, they all have it becouse it's mandatory to add new operations. I can show you the console.log answer if it helps

Comment: _they all have_ this is impossible I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for null or undefined value before accessing it.
you could add condition here

```
let entryArray = operationsListCopy.filter((oneOperation) => oneOperation?.type == 'INCOME');
```

and here

```
 let exitArray = operationsListCopy.filter((oneOperation) => oneOperation?.type == 'EXPENSE');
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks @Yaroslav !